# What's the different between platform OpenCL version and device?

Tags: opencl

Specifically, I have single platform version **2.1** with single device version **2.0** and I want to use **C++14** features which supported only in **OpenCL 2.1**. Should I be able to? What matters when it comes to capabilities limitation: platform or device? What's even the point of *platform version* since it always comes down to using device anyway?

Answer (score 5):

> What's even the point of platform version since it always comes down to using device 
>   anyway?

Platform = version of the codebase and API etc.

Device = Capabilities of the hardware.

The sense is that a platform update may change the way you write your code USING the API, while the device capabilities may change with the hardawre chip.

Comment: So when I compile/build kernel with [clBuildProgram()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clBuildProgram.html) within the kernel code should I rely on **OpenCL** having version 2.1 from platform or 2.0 from device?

Comment: Yes, and WITHIN OCL 2.1 you can check platform features. "simple" changes activating or disbling them. OCL 3.0 may have a totally different API and may require major rework. DirectX 12, i.e., changed a LOT - to allow multithreading, even though the graphics cards did not change at the time the whole frontend looked VERY different for the application.

Comment: "yes" meaning targeting **platform** version or **device** version? Also, I don't fully understand what DirectX12 means here?